# How do I implement IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I know how to implement the non generic IEnumerable, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyObjects myObjects = new MyObjects();
            myObjects[0] = new MyObject() { Foo = "Hello", Bar = 1 };
            myObjects[1] = new MyObject() { Foo = "World", Bar = 2 };

            foreach (MyObject x in myObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Foo);
                Console.WriteLine(x.Bar);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MyObject
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public int Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class MyObjects : IEnumerable
    {
        ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();

        public MyObject this[int index]
        {
            get { return (MyObject)mylist[index]; }
            set { mylist.Insert(index, value); }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return mylist.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

However I also notice that IEnumerable has a generic version, `IEnumerable<T>`, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

If I add `using System.Collections.Generic;` to my using directives, and then change:

```
class MyObjects : IEnumerable
```

to:

```
class MyObjects : IEnumerable<MyObject>
```

And then right click on `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and select `Implement Interface => Implement Interface`, Visual Studio helpfully adds the following block of code:

```
IEnumerator<MyObject> IEnumerable<MyObject>.GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Returning the non generic IEnumerable object from the `GetEnumerator();` method doesn't work this time, so what do I put here? The CLI now ignores the non generic implementation and heads straight for the generic version when it tries to enumerate through my array during the foreach loop.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

If you choose to use a generic collection, such as `List<MyObject>` instead of `ArrayList`, you'll find that the `List<MyObject>` will provide both generic and non-generic enumerators that you can use.

```
using System.Collections;

class MyObjects : IEnumerable<MyObject>
{
    List<MyObject> mylist = new List<MyObject>();

    public MyObject this[int index]  
    {  
        get { return mylist[index]; }  
        set { mylist.Insert(index, value); }  
    } 

    public IEnumerator<MyObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return mylist.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the non-generic implementation, is there a difference between returning `this.GetEnumerator()` and simply returning `GetEnumerator()`?

Comment: @TannerSwett There is no difference.

Comment: You might as well inherit from `Collection<MyObject>` and then you won't have to write any custom code.

Comment: @ja72 What if you're already inheriting from another base class and cannot inherit from Collection<MyObject>?

Comment: @MonroeThomas - then you have to wrap `List<T>` and implement `IEnumerable<T>` as shown in your answer.

Answer (score 89):

You probably do not want an *explicit* implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` (which is what you've shown).

The usual pattern is to use `IEnumerable<T>`'s `GetEnumerator` in the explicit implementation of `IEnumerable`:

```
class FooCollection : IEnumerable<Foo>, IEnumerable
{
    SomeCollection<Foo> foos;

    // Explicit for IEnumerable because weakly typed collections are Bad
    System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // uses the strongly typed IEnumerable<T> implementation
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Normal implementation for IEnumerable<T>
    IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Foo foo in this.foos)
        {
            yield return foo;
            //nb: if SomeCollection is not strongly-typed use a cast:
            // yield return (Foo)foo;
            // Or better yet, switch to an internal collection which is
            // strongly-typed. Such as List<T> or T[], your choice.
        }

        // or, as pointed out: return this.foos.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if SomeCollection<T> does not already implement IEnumerable<T>, or if you need to transform or do other processing on each element before it is returned in the enumeration sequence.  If neither of these conditions are true, then it is probably more efficient to just return this.foos.GetEnumerator();

Comment: @MonroeThomas: agreed. No clue what collection the OP is using.

Comment: Good point. But implementing `IEnumerable` is redundant (`IEnumerable<T>` already inherits from it).

Comment: @rsenna that's true, however keep in mind even .NET interfaces like IList redundantly implement interfaces, it's for readability - public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I actually (still) think it makes less readable, since it adds unnecessary noise, but I understand what you said, and think it's a valid opinion.

Answer (score 26):

Why do you do it manually? [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) automates the entire process of handling iterators. (I also wrote about it [on my blog](http://coding.abel.nu/2011/12/return-ienumerable-with-yield-return/), including a look at the compiler generated code).

If you really  want to do it yourself, you have to return a generic enumerator too. You won't be able to use an `ArrayList` any more since that's non-generic. Change it to a `List<MyObject>` instead. That of course assumes that you only have objects of type `MyObject` (or derived types) in your collection.

Comment: +1, it should be noted that the preferred pattern is to implement the generic interface and explicitly implement the non-generic interface. Yield return  is the most natural solution to the generic interface.

Comment: Unless the OP is going to be doing some processing in the enumerator, using yield return just adds the overhead of another state machine.  The OP should just return an enumerator provided by an underlying generic collection.

Comment: @MonroeThomas: You're right. I didn't read the question very carefully before writing about `yield return`. I wrongly assumed that there were some custom processing.

Answer (score 5):

If you work with generics, use List instead of ArrayList. The List has exactly the GetEnumerator method you need.

```
List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
```

Answer (score 0):

make mylist into a `List<MyObject>`, is one option

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `IEnumerable<T>` allready implemented by the `System.Collections` so another approach is to derive your `MyObjects` class from `System.Collections` as a base class ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

> System.Collections: Provides the base class for a generic collection.

We can later make our own implemenation to override the virtual `System.Collections` methods to provide custom behavior (only for `ClearItems`, `InsertItem`, `RemoveItem`, and `SetItem` along with `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, and `ToString` from `Object`). Unlike the `List<T>` which is not designed to be easily extensible.

Example:

```
public class FooCollection : System.Collections<Foo>
{
    //...
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Foo newItem)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, newItem);     
        Console.Write("An item was successfully inserted to MyCollection!");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    FooCollection fooCollection = new FooCollection();
    fooCollection.Add(new Foo()); //OUTPUT: An item was successfully inserted to FooCollection!
}
```

Please note that driving from `collection` recommended only in case when custom collection behavior is needed, which is rarely happens. see [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679777/6844481).

Answer (score 0):

.... and do not forget the using if you are blocked by

```
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // uses the strongly typed IEnumerable<T> implementation
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

add this:

```
using System.Collections;
```

also:

```
: IEnumerable<string>
```

is sufficient has it is embedding the IEnumerable:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

... also beware of Syntax jokes between the A in enumrAble and the o in enumratOr which are both used in this pattern !
Nice dangerous line:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```