# Use foreach on a class not a collection of a class

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerator

So I have a this class with strings, floats, DateTimes, and data tables

```
public class Data : IEnumerator
{

    string m_PowerSwitch = "Not Tested",
        m_SerialNumber = "Not Tested",
        m_Reset = "Not Tested",
        m_WashPump = "Not Tested",

        m_PortB = "Not Tested",
        m_PortC = "Not Tested",
        m_PortD = "Not Tested",
        m_CurlyTube = "Not Tested",
        m_BypassTube = "Not Tested";

    float m_EC53115VMeasured = 0.0F,
        m_EC53165VMeasured = 0.0F,
        m_EC531624VMeasured = 0.0F,

        m_SolventLineBVolumeMeasured = 0.0F,
        m_SolventLineCVolumeMeasured = 0.0F,
        m_SolventLineDVolumeMeasured = 0.0F,
        m_CurlyTubeVolumeMeasured = 0.0F,
        m_BypassTubeVolumeMeasured = 0.0F;
}
```

I want to use a foreach statement such as

```
        foreach (ASM001.ASM asm in P00001.Global.ListofAvailableASMs)
        {  
            if (asm.ASMData.EndTime == null)
                asm.ASMData.EndTime = endTime;

            foreach (object data in asm.ASMData)
            {
                if (data == "Not Tested")
                {
                    asm.ASMData.Result = "FAILED";
                }
                continue;
            }
```

but I have not been able to find any help of searching through the individual fields of a class, just on a list of the class type.

I am getting the error 
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ASM001.Data' because 'ASM001.Data' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I was wondering if this was possible or if I was going to have to hard code checking each string field by name and returning true or false.

And just so you now there are a lot more strings than what I copied I would have to check, which is why I was wondering if there was a quicker way to do it.

Comment: shouldn't it be `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerator`?

Comment: @Grant each string has a public property that excludes the m_

Comment: @DLeh it very well could be but that still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @JoshDavis well it solves the error of `does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: You cannot enumerator over class fields like that.  You will need to use reflection and pull the list of fields.

Comment: @JamesWilkins that's not true. foreach can be used on anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, doing it for a type that doesn't represent some kind of sequence of items doesn't make a whole lot of sense but it's certainly possible. To the OP you're implementing the wrong interface. The Enumator bit of it is just a small part of what's required to make a type 'foreachable' (enumberable). This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet

Comment: That's not what I meant.  You cannot just an "IEnumerator" to a class to read its properties, nor "IEnumerable<>".  You CAN, however, implement the interface methods to read the class fields if you program it to do so (but whether or not one should is another topic all together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Reflection (code paraphrased, this will not build)

```
Data data = ...
Type type = data.GetType();
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(...);
foreach(FieldInfo field in fields) {

    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue( data ) );
}
```

Comment: Should have stated each field had a public property which is what I looking at but that was a simple fix and was able to figure it out from what you said

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the following example *should* build and run):

> The following example retrieves the fields of MyClass and displays the
>   field values.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class MyClass
{
    public string myFieldA;
    public string myFieldB; 
    public MyClass()
    {
        myFieldA = "A public field";
        myFieldB = "Another public field";
    }
}

public class FieldInfo_GetValue
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
        // Get the type of MyClass.
        Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
        try
        {
            // Get the FieldInfo of MyClass.
            FieldInfo[] myFields = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public 
                | BindingFlags.Instance);
            // Display the values of the fields.
            Console.WriteLine("\nDisplaying the values of the fields of {0}.\n",
                myType);
            for(int i = 0; i < myFields.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value of {0} is: {1}",
                    myFields[i].Name, myFields[i].GetValue(myInstance));
            }
        }  
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only pull the public fields?

Comment: Hmm, I am not immediately sure of that. I'll dig into it some more

Comment: From the article I linked: 
"Access restrictions are ignored for fully trusted code. That is, private constructors, methods, fields, and properties can be accessed and invoked through reflection whenever the code is fully trusted."

Answer (score 1):

Possible LINQ version:

```
Data data = ...
FieldInfo[] fields = (from f in data.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic) where f.Name.StartsWith("m_") select f).ToArray();
```