# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#

I can't understand why this error occurs:

```
public string GetStatusText(string abc) {
   string status = "";

   STATUSDTO StatusList = new STATUSDTO();
   StatusList.LoadByMasterWayBill(abc);

   // this method return List<STATUSDTO>    

   bool has190s = false;
   bool hasother = false;

   foreach(V_TMSDetail_STATUSDTO v in StatusList) {
       if (v.Status == "190" || v.Status == "191") has190s = true;
       else hasother = true;
   }

   if (has190s && hasother) status = "Partially Submitted";
   else if (has190s && !hasother) status = "Submitted";
   else if (!has190s && hasother) status = "Not Submitted";

   return status;
}
```

When I compile this program, it gives me this error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type  because  does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What type is `vTMSDetailStatusList`? How is it declared?

Comment: i edit my question u check that

Comment: We need to see the type declaration of `STATUSDTO` to verify that it is the proper enumerable type.

Comment: According error, `StatusList` doesn't implement `IEnumerable` what disallow using it on a `foreach` loop

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment but this helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` statement in C# does only work on collections that implement the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or the `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`. The error that you get tells you that the collection you have does not contain a definition for the public `GetEnumerator` method, which is provided by these interfaces.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Its a guess based on the hanging comment...   `StatusList` does not implement an enumerator.  I'm guessing you are trying to loop over the list that is returned by `LoadByMasterWayBill`

```
var myList = StatusList.LoadByMasterWayBill(abc);

foreach(V_TMSDetail_STATUSDTO v in myList) {
   //code above
}
```