# Why I can't use OrderBy despite having GetEnumerator and foreach working well?

Tags: c#, linq, enumerator

I've implemented the `GetEnumerator` method for a simple class and was surprised that I couldn't order the enumerator with linq (a call to `this.OrderBy(x => x)` is invalid). Can someone please explain what's going on here? Am I doing something wrong or are enumerators only intended to be iterated over?

```
class Test
{
    private Dictionary<int, string> dict
        = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Test()
    {
        dict[1] = "test";
        dict[2] = "nothing";
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> SortedKeys
    {
        get { return this.OrderBy(x => x); } // illegal!
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach(var key in this)
            Console.WriteLine(dict[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to implement the interface `IEnumerable<int>` in order for the `this.OrderBy` to work, how else should it know `this` can enumerate `int`s?

`OrderBy` requires `this` to implement `IEnumerable<T>`. It doesn't know your `GetEnumerator` method is actually an attempt to comply to the interface.

`foreach` just requires a `GetEnumerator()` method, no interface implementatio needed.

```
// put in the interface
class Test : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private Dictionary<int, string> dict
        = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Test()
    {
        dict[1] = "test";
        dict[2] = "nothing";
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> SortedKeys
    {
        get { return this.OrderBy(x => x); } // illegal!
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (var key in this)
            Console.WriteLine(dict[key]);
    }

    // this one is required according to the interface too
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy()` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.
Your class does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

`foreach` still works, because it does not require you to implement `IEnumerable<T>`; it only requires that there is a method `GetEnumerator()`.

So all you need to do is add:

```
class Test : IEnumerable<int>
```

and provide the implementation for the non-generic `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An enumerator is an *iterator*. It's just an interface that tells the runtime or custom code on how to move to a next element in some sequence, reset the iteration to the first element again or get current element in the iteration.

That is, an enumerator isn't enumerable. An enumerable can create an enumerator to let other code enumerate the enumeration.

In order to be able to call a LINQ extension method you need *the object* to be enumerable. Your `Test` class doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` (LINQ extension method signatures look like this: `public static IEnumerable<T> Whatever<T>(this IEnumerable<T> someEnumerable)`).

Since I want to apply DRY principle on myself (Don't Repeat Yourself), if you want to know how to implement `IEnumerable<T>` you should look at the following Q&A: [How do I implement IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet).