# IEnumerable Class Collection type conversion from List

Tags: c#, class, ienumerable

I am trying to understand IEnumerable collections. I have a basic WorkOrder class and I'm wanting to make a collection class for it.

WorkOrder.cs

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    public string WONumber { get; private set; }
    public string WIP { get; private set; }

    public WorkOrder()
    {
        WONumber = "384327";
        WIP = "3483";
    }
}
```

I have started the collection class but I'm getting an error at `this.workorders.GetEnumerator()`. It is telling me that it cannot convert a List to an Enumerator.

```
public class WorkOrderCollection : IEnumerable<WorkOrder>
{
    private List<WorkOrder> workorders = new List<WorkOrder>();

    public IEnumerable<WorkOrder> GetEnumerater() 
    { 
        return this.workorders.GetEnumerator(); 
    }

    public WorkOrderCollection()
    {
    }

    public void Add(WorkOrder aWorkOrder)
    {
       workorders.Add(aWorkOrder);
    }

    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        if (index > workorders.Count - 1 || index < 0)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Index not valid!");
    }
    else
    {
        workorders.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

I am not fully understanding this. What do I need to do to make this convert?

Comment: you should refer to this post :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet

Comment: Apart from that, may I ask why you're building a collection class yourself? Why not simply use a `List<WorkOrder>` directly? Your collection doesn't does much other than simply delegating everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should not be:

```
public IEnumerable<WorkOrder> GetEnumerater() 
{ 
    return this.workorders.GetEnumerator(); 
}
```

only

```
public IEnumerator<WorkOrder> GetEnumerater() 
{ 
    return this.workorders.GetEnumerator(); 
}
```

that is, `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable` as a return type.

I don't know your use case, but why not simply?:

```
public class WorkOrderCollection : List<WorkOrder>
{
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what would be best practice. What would be the benefits to each (List vs IEnumerable)?

Comment: Less code with inheriting `List<T>`. I would say that you should use `IEnumerable<T>` when you don't need the functionalities of a list, like getting values per index, adding new values etc. but you are using a list inside of it, and your class is only a wrapper around the inside list implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, in that case, I don't see a reason to hide the list functionalities, and when you need them, another wrapper methods will have to be written. Not knowing the use case - I would go with inheriting the List

Comment: As  you can see, I am not clear on collections side of a class. I have hacked this together. I'm confused on how I would do this.

Comment: When it comes to testing it is preferable to have as few methods as possible on your types. If you extend `List` you get a lot of methods you would possibly need to mock out in order to test your code properly. Furthermore it tightly couples the accessing code to a specific implementation.