# foreach and traditional for-loop with List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, c++, list, foreach, iterator

In C#, I just found out there's no such thing like an **iterator** of C++ or Java. In C++, I was advised not to iterate **Linked Lists** with indices because there would be a performance impact accessing from the first node on every loop. But it seems that I got only two choices in C#. Traditional **for-loop** VS **foreach**.

Is it different in C#? No performance issues with for-loop unlike in C++?

I also heard `foreach` creates every new variable in every loop iteration like in Java so I don't know which one would fit for low-end mobile phones.

Comment: *I just found out there's no such thing like an iterator*, [Yes, there is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx), that's what makes iteration with `foreach` possible. Perhaps you want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet) as well.

Comment: You heard wrong. *also heard foreach creates every new variable in every loop iteration like in Java* It doesn't. Java doesn't either.

Comment: Oops! really? Thanks!! then, it's better with an iterator?? Don't use for-loop??

Comment: I'm not sure what *better* means to you, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I mean, as I said above, in C++ I was told not to use for-loop with a Linked List because a Linked List can't be access by an index directly unlike arrays, and it's not cheap, so curious if it's the same in C#.

Comment: @JenixGuy I would advise you to look at how the [`IEnumerator<LinkedList>` is implemented in the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,8c5f1e7efe8052ad). Perhaps you'll learn what they did and understand if it fits your needs.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I see, thank you so much!

Comment: @Dennis_E Really?? I was taught it did.. for(int each: new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})
 System.out.println(each); this doesn't?? The variable each can't be modified..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question completely, but still wanted to point out that this assumption is false:

> In C#, I just found out there's no such thing like an iterator of C++ or Java

It's called an enumerator in C#, see [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also consider this code sample using a traditional `for`-loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new List<int> { 7, 10, 0 };
    for (var it = data.GetEnumerator(); it.MoveNext(); )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(it.Current);
    }
}
```

Anyway, I don't think anyone is iterating a list or `IEnumerable` like in this sample :)

Comment: Is that seriously how you'd iterate a `List<T>` in a for-loop? What's wrong with the "regular" `for (int i = i; i < list.Count; i++) Console.WriteLine(list[i]);`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I never use this and it also doesn't answer the whole question, but did you actually read the OP?

Comment: Just want to demonstrate that you can use an enumerator in a normal `for` loop like you would in C++, anyway it doesn't answer the question so I might remove it

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Thanks! No no don't remove!

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I did read the OP, and I definitely didn't understand it as "How do I iterate an iterator inside a `for` loop". If that is the question, then I'll remove my comment :)

Comment: As both of you said, it seems this is not the normal way of doing things but really like this answer because I'm new to C# and didn't know such thing like this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept of iterator in C#, it's `IEnumerable<T>`, and it can provide sequential access to a collection.

`List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` both implement this interface, and there is no performance penalty associated with algorithmic complexity of the indexing operation in both cases.

As a side note, the `LinkedList<T>` has no benefit of fast append operation in .NET, since `List<T>` has O(1) amortized time when adding an item to the end of the list, and `List<T>` makes less pressure on GC, because it's backed by array storage growing exponentially when needed, so you end up using `List<T>` most of the time.

As for the performance of indexed access of `List<T>` and 'same variable' issue, i think following code demonstrates the usage scenarios.

In the 'same variable' check, you can see that in case of 'for' the variable is in outer scope, and for the `foreach` it's in the inner scope for the iterator block in recent compiler versions (need to check which version changed this). 
It's very important in case you make a closure, and the code demonstrates it.

```
void Main()
{
    var n = 10000000;
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToList();

    var array = list.ToArray();

    Test(TestForeach, list, "foreach - List");
    Test(TestFor, list, "for - List");

    Test(TestForeach, array, "foreach - Array");
    Test(TestFor, array, "for - Array");

    TestSameVariableFor();
    TestSameVariableForeach();
}

void TestSameVariableFor()
{
    var sum = 0;
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        actions.Add(() => sum += i);
    }

    foreach (var a in actions)
    {
        a();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("For - Sum is {0}", sum);
}

void TestSameVariableForeach()
{
    var sum = 0;
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
    {
        actions.Add(() => sum += i);
    }

    foreach (var a in actions)
    {
        a();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Foreach - Sum is {0}", sum);
}

void Test(Action<List<int>> action, List<int> list, string what)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action(list);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed {0}, {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, what);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

void Test(Action<int[]> action, int[] list, string what)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action(list);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed {0}, {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, what);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

void TestFor(List<int> list)
{
    long sum = 0;

    var count = list.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}

void TestForeach(List<int> list)
{
    long sum = 0;

    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}

void TestFor(int[] list)
{
    long sum = 0;

    var count = list.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}

void TestForeach(int[] list)
{
    long sum = 0;

    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Output:

```
49999995000000
Elapsed 37, foreach - List

49999995000000
Elapsed 6, for - List

49999995000000
Elapsed 7, foreach - Array

49999995000000
Elapsed 6, for - Array

For - Sum is 4
Foreach - Sum is 1
```

Update:
Here is the post describing the `foreach` semantics change:
[Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach/12249317#12249317)

Comment: You are welcome. Updated the answer to fix mistakes and added a note about the `LinkedList<T>`