# cannot initialize type because it does not implement 'system.collections.ienumerable' mvc eror

Tags: c#

```
List<Models.ViewModels.GetCVList_ViewModel> list = _context.Can_CVs
  .Where(x => x.isDeleted == false)
  .Select(x => new GetCVList_ViewModel { x.Title, x.CVID, x.CityID, x.EditDate, x.AddDate })
  .ToList();
```

this code 
I'm using the CV tables specific column to list.
 but column types are different so I can't

how can I do? thanks

Comment: did you read this article ? [How do I implement IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet)

Comment: ok reading now thx Dindarkdevil

Comment: public class GetCVList_ViewModel
    {        
        public string Title {get; set;}
        public int CVID { get; set; }
        public short? CityID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EditDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should assing each model property to corresponding viewmodel propety:

```
.Select(x => new GetCVList_ViewModel
{ 
    Title = x.Title,
    CVID = x.CVID,
    CityID = x.CityID,
    EditDate = x.EditDate,
    AddDate = x.AddDate
})
```

Comment: ok very thanks I can,I'm using the CV tables specific column to list so very thanks ;)