# How to implement Iterator pattern (IEnumerator<T>) without the yield statement

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, ienumerator

How could I rewrite `GetEnumerator` method without using `yield` keyword?
Code of method:

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return 1;

    Console.WriteLine("1");

    yield return 2;
}
```

I just what to know how it can be implemented manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet)

Comment: The IL generated from any IEnumerator is always generating a yield statement as far as I know. I'd check this if I was you, you could be trying to generate some performance benefit descoping local variables for GC  collection that the IL just pulls back in.

Comment: @CodeNotFound The OP's question is *not* how to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but how to implement `IEnumerator<T>` manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, the `yield` statement is a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that makes the compiler actually generate a class which implements the `IEnumerator<T>` interface and rewrites the body of the method using the `yield` statement into a state machine.

Each state is associated with a portion of code that ultimately generates the next element in the sequence. This is embedded in the `MoveNext()` method. A state machine can represent all necessary constructs (a sequence, a selection, an iteration) and hence all C# code (meaning statements within a method) can be rewritten like that. That is the underlying 'magic' of `yield`.

In your specific case, such rewriting into a state machine and the corresponding full implementation of `IEnumerator<T>` (and its inherited `IEnumerator` (non-generic) and `IDisposable` interfaces) will look like this:

```
public class CustomEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
    public int Current { get; private set; }

    object IEnumerator.Current => this.Current;

    // internal 'position' in the sequence, i.e. the current state of the state machine
    private int position = 0;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        // advance to next state 
        // (works for linear algorithms; an alternative is to select the next state at the end of processing the current state)
        position++;

        // perform the code associated with the current state and produce an element
        switch (position)
        {
            // state 1: line 'yield return 1;'
            case 1:
                Current = 1;
                return true;

            // state 2: lines 'Console.WriteLine("1");' and 'yield return 2;'
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("1"); // see also note at the end of this answer
                Current = 2;
                return true;

            // there are no other states in this state machine
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = 0;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // nothing to do here   
    }
}
```

Each call to `MoveNext()`, which is what happens internally in each iteration of a `foreach` statement, causes a portion of the code to be executed—until the next element in the sequence is produced.

For this implementation to be usable, a corresponding `IEnumerable<T>` implementation is necessary, which is pretty trivial:

```
public class CustomEnumerable : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CustomEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then the following two `foreach` loops will produce the exact same results:

```
void Main()
{
    // custom implementation of IEnumerator<T>
    foreach (int i in new CustomEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }   

    // your original implementation—will produce same results
    // note: I assume someObject implements IEnumerable<T> and hence your GetEnumerator() method
    foreach (int i in someObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }   
}
```

*Note: In your `GetEnumerator()` code the call to `Console.WriteLine("1");` is **after** the enumerator returns `1` (and the caller processes it) so that looks a little bit odd.*