# foreach of IEnumerable<T> always calls non-generic Enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have created an object and implemented the interface `IEnumerable<Options>`.
If I try to loop through my object it is working fine but the variables aren't casted to a `Options` but `object`.

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<Options>
{
    // I just cut the non-relevant code. The real class is over 500 lines ...

    public List<Options> options = new List<Options>();

    IEnumerator<Options> IEnumerable<Options>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return options.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return options.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

How I loop through:

```
foreach (var option in myClass)
{
    // Do something
}
```

`typeof(option)` returns `object`. But since I implemented the generic interface I want it to be returned as `Options`. It is indeed an `Options` object I can explicitly cast it with `(Options)option` but it should be automatically casted.

```
foreach (Options option in myClass)
{
   // I want it to be casted automatically when using 'var'
}
```

Comment: You have made the generic GetEnumerator method from the generic IEnumerable<T> interface an explicit interface implementation. Try making the non-generic IEnumerable.GetEnumerator an explicit interface implementation instead, and declare the generic GetEnumerator normally (i.e., not as an explicit interface implementation) Not tested/verified myself, but i believe that's the root of your pain...

Comment: Reopened since it seems to be different to [How do I implement IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Seems the same to me, it shows how to correctly implement these two interfaces together

Comment: @Charlieface:  you're right, if you use that code this will work as well. `public IEnumerator<Options> GetEnumerator(){ return options.GetEnumerator(); }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the C# language reference, [12.9.5 The foreach statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement):

> The compile-time processing of a `foreach` statement first determines the **collection type, enumerator type and iteration type** of the expression. This determination proceeds as follows:
>
> - If the type `X` of expression is an array type then there is an implicit reference conversion from `X` to the `IEnumerable` interface (since `System.Array` implements this interface). The collection type is the `IEnumerable` interface, the enumerator type is the `IEnumerator` interface and the iteration type is the element type of the array type X.
> - If the type `X` of expression is `dynamic` then there is an implicit conversion from expression to the `IEnumerable` interface (§10.2.10). The collection type is the `IEnumerable` interface and the enumerator type is the `IEnumerator` interface. If the `var` identifier is given as the *local_variable_type* then the iteration type is `dynamic`, otherwise it is `object`.
> - Otherwise, determine whether the type `X` has an appropriate `GetEnumerator` method:
>
>   - Perform member lookup on the type `X` with identifier `GetEnumerator` and no type arguments. If the member lookup does not produce a match, or it produces an ambiguity, or produces a match that is not a method group, check for an enumerable interface as described below. It is recommended that a warning be issued if member lookup produces anything except a method group or no match.
>   - Perform overload resolution using the resulting method group and an empty argument list. If overload resolution results in no applicable methods, results in an ambiguity, or results in a single best method but that method is either static or not public, check for an enumerable interface as described below. It is recommended that a warning be issued if overload resolution produces anything except an unambiguous public instance method or no applicable methods.
>   - If the return type `E` of the `GetEnumerator` method is not a class, struct or interface type, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
>   - Member lookup is performed on `E` with the identifier `Current` and no type arguments. If the member lookup produces no match, the result is an error, or the result is anything except a public instance property that permits reading, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
>   - Member lookup is performed on `E` with the identifier `MoveNext` and no type arguments. If the member lookup produces no match, the result is an error, or the result is anything except a method group, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
>   - Overload resolution is performed on the method group with an empty argument list. If overload resolution results in no applicable methods, results in an ambiguity, or results in a single best method but that method is either static or not public, or its return type is not bool, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
>   - The collection type is `X`, the enumerator type is `E`, and the iteration type is the type of the `Current` property.
> - Otherwise, check for an enumerable interface:
>
>   - If among all the types `Tᵢ` for which there is an implicit conversion from `X` to `IEnumerable<Tᵢ>`, there is a unique type `T` such that `T` is not dynamic and for all the other `Tᵢ` there is an implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<Tᵢ>`, then the collection type is the interface `IEnumerable<T>`, the enumerator type is the interface `IEnumerator<T>`, and the iteration type is `T`.
>   - Otherwise, if there is more than one such type `T`, then an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
>   - Otherwise, if there is an implicit conversion from `X` to the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface, then the collection type is this interface, the enumerator type is the interface `System.Collections.IEnumerator`, and the iteration type is object.
>   - Otherwise, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.

So in your case the compiler found a public `GetEnumerator` method in the `MyClass`, which happened to be a method that returns an `IEnumerator`, and was happy to use this method for the `foreach` enumeration because the criteria were satisfied. There was no reason to go a step down and check for an enumerable interface, so the explicitly implemented `IEnumerable<Options>.GetEnumerator` method was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In the `foreach` the compiler does not see the generic version of the `GetEnumerator` method, because you are implementing it *explicitly*, and hence without a cast to `IEnumerable<Options>` the `IEnumerable` implementation is used, yielding `object`s.

With your current implementation you'd have to do:

```
foreach (var option in (IEnumerable<Options>) myClass)
```

then `option` is of type `Options`.

You should implement the non-generic version explicitly, and the generic version implicitly. Then it works as you expect:

```
public IEnumerator<Options> GetEnumerator()
{
    return options.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return options.GetEnumerator();
}
```

and the type of `var option` will be `Options`.

*Update: For those interested in the full `GetEnumerator()` resolution algorithm, which is fairly complex, see [the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement), plus [improvements in C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams) and [in C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/extension-getenumerator).*

Comment: *"the compiler does not see the generic version of the `GetEnumerator` method, because you are implementing it explicitly"* -- This doesn't explain why the compiler uses the generic version, when both the generic and the non-generic are implementing explicitly...

Comment: [SharpLab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgMIHsA2mCmBjAFwEt0A7AZwG4BYAKFgUQBYba6oAmRgdjoG86cIQg4dBwgbWHS4AM3QAnHAEM8ACzgAKAG7KFcAPpwipOKRwB3OAFkAnqkzLy5TQEpXcPnAC+4ob9oA9i47BydyOBBGAGYAHhMCAD5+PzgAejSoaLgASQBRUgBXAFscBWUCRXjSJLgAcRwCApKyisU3OABeRLhgHFllQswCVml8otLyyoVq2qQ4hMTkBqaJ1umO7t7+weHWVIys3ObJtv0Vk/X2jy2+gaGR1PGWqcUY5cbL14VNnrvdx6BOhAA) with both `GetEnumerator` implementing explicitly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Because the compiler gives precedence to `IEnumerable<T>`. The search algorithm for the suitable `GetEnumerator` method is fairly complex and described [in the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement). Btw. you don't need to expose any `IEnumerable` at all, just given the compiler a suitable public `GetEnumerator` method satisfying certain criteria.

Comment: Ondrej sure, but shouldn't you include this detail in the answer?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What's more valuable for the OP? A practical answer with a reasonably simple explanation, or a theoretical answer citing a two-page abstract description from the language spec which hardly anyone ever reads in detail?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Btw you are welcome to improve my answer.

Comment: Ondrej I am not sure what the OP would do if they had to choose between a purely practical and a purely theoretical answer. I am just pointing out that the statement *"the compiler does not see the generic version of the `GetEnumerator` method, because you are implementing it explicitly"* is not accurate. If you don't want to be detailed, you could cut this statement out, and your answer will be improved IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Ah, you are right, fixed. Wrong copy & paste from LINQPad.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Regarding your suggestion to _remove_ the sentence _"the compiler does not see the generic version of the GetEnumerator method, because you are implementing it explicitly"_ — no, I don't believe this would anyhow “improve” my question. The reason is, it's a _fact_. In the OP's case the compiler can see _exactly one_ public `GetEnumerator` method, which is `public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` and the resolution algorithm stops at that point. No interfaces get ever inspected.

Comment: Ondrej no, it's not a fact, it's part of a fact. Your answer does not present the whole fact, and this could cause people taking your answer at face value to reach wrong conclusions. The wrong conclusion is that "if you implement explicitly the `GetEnumerator`, the compiler will never be able to see it", which is false.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No, _“"if you implement explicitly the GetEnumerator, the compiler will never be able to see it"”_, is not a conclusion that could be drawn from my answer. From A ⇒ B you cannot reason about B ⇒ A. My answer covers the OPs problem and I have no intention in copy & pasting a two-page spec to it. Please let's end this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement the interface `IEnumerable` explicitly, and `IEnumerable<T>` publicly

```
public IEnumerator<Options> GetEnumerator()
{
    return options.GetEnumerator();
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

So the default is the generic function, and the non-generic is called only explicitly.